# Помогите дописать меленькый JavaScript код по увеличению числа в поле input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой скрипт

```
function timer() {
var seconds = 5;
var seconds_timer_id = setInterval(function() {
            if (seconds > 0) {
                seconds --;
                if (seconds < 10) {
                    seconds = "0" + seconds;
                }
                $(".videotime").text(seconds);
            } else {
                clearInterval(seconds_timer_id);
                $("#allcount").val((+$("#allcount").val() + 1));

            }
        }, 1000);

    }
```

Который я запускаю так

```
<a href="index.php?id=test1" rel="prettyPopin" onclick="timer(); this.style.display='none';">Старт</a>
```

Когда скрипт запускается первый раз то он увеличивает значение в поле input на единицу, а когда я питаюсь запустить его второй раз ничего не преисходит. Вернее тймер идет но увеличения нет.

Форма в которой должно увеличеватся число

```js
function timer() {
  var seconds = 5;
  var seconds_timer_id = setInterval(function() {
    if (seconds > 0) {
      seconds --;
      if (seconds < 10) {
        seconds = "0" + seconds;
      }
      $(".videotime").text(seconds);
    } else {
      clearInterval(seconds_timer_id);
      $("#allcount").val((+$("#allcount").val() + 1));
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="videotime">0</div>

<form id="formMain" name="formMain">
<input type="text" value="0" id="allcount" name="counttest"  />
</form>

<a href="#" rel="prettyPopin" onclick="timer(); this.style.display='none';">Смотреть видео</a><br>

<a href="#" rel="prettyPopin" onclick="timer(); this.style.display='none';">Смотреть видео</a><br>

<a href="#" rel="prettyPopin" onclick="timer(); this.style.display='none';">Смотреть видео</a><br>

<a href="#" rel="prettyPopin" onclick="timer(); this.style.display='none';">Смотреть видео</a><br>

<a href="#" rel="prettyPopin" onclick="timer(); this.style.display='none';">Смотреть видео</a><br>

<a href="#" rel="prettyPopin" onclick="timer(); this.style.display='none';">Смотреть видео</a><br>
```

Comment: `$("#allcount").val((+$("#allcount").val() + 1));` Непонятно, какой смысл в проверке `(seconds < 10)`, если `seconds` начинается с числа 5 и уменьшется.

Comment: @Igor работает только раз, вставил Ваш код при первом запуске скрипта сработало только раз, показало 1 а когда опять запускаю скрипт не работает. Скрипт запускаю так 'onclick="timer();'

Comment: @Igor Чет не понятно мне если пишу так то все работает  
<a onclick="timer();">asdas</a> а если вот так то нет <a href="#" rel="prettyPopin" onclick="timer(); this.style.display='none';" class="template_button">Смотреть видео</a> то не работает.

Comment: предлагаю Вам отредактировать вопрос. Когда перейдете в режим редактирования - обратите внимание на кнопку, позволяющую создать работающий фрагмент javascript'a и html'a, - легче будет понять, в чем дело.

Comment: @Igor тут все работает, а у меня чет не хочет, добавляет единице тока раз и все.

Comment: Вот видите, значит код рабочий. Осталось только найти, что у Вас отличается от "здесь".

Comment: @Igor у меня когда на ссылку кликаеш еще открывается всаливающие окошко в которое загружается контент с другой страницы, по видимому в этом и проблема. Но таймер работает харашо, а вот +1 срабатывает только раз. А нет другой альтернативы для $("#allcount").val((+$("#allcount").val() + 1));

Comment: Ну-у-у, например, если "контент с другой страницы" содержит элемент с `id="allcount"`, то это может все поломать. Замените "allcount" на что-то более уникальное.

Comment: @Igor не помагает,  и контент который грузится с другой страницы с этим не путается. Все, наверное ставлю на этом точку. Сегодня целей день с этой задачей проигрался.

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день, переписал твой код.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MbgxzL?editors=1111

Сделал 2 разных таймера, когда первый заканчивает свою работу, мы его удаляем с помощью **clearInterbal** и запускаем новый, который уже увеличивает значение инпута каждый раз на 1

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="videotime">0</div>
<form id="formMain" name="formMain">
<input type="text" value="0" id="allcount" name="counttest"  />
</form>
<a href="#" rel="prettyPopin" class="seeVideo">Смотреть видео</a><br>

<!-- JS -->
$(document).on('ready', function(){

  var secAdvt = 6;
  var timeStart = 0;

  function timer(obj) {
    timeStart++;
    $("input[name=counttest]").val(timeStart);
  }

  function countdown(obj){
    secAdvt--;

    if(secAdvt == 0){
      clearInterval(startCountDown);
      startVideo = setInterval(function(){
        timer();
      }, 1000);
    }

    $(".videotime").text(secAdvt);
  }

  $(".seeVideo").on('click', function(){
    $(".videotime").text();
    startCountDown = setInterval(function(){
      countdown();
    }, 1000);
  });

});
```

Comment: А вообще в вашем коде логическая ошибка в том, что для счетчика используется одна переменная, можно переписать на 1 таймер, просто будет 2 счетчика. Один для рекламы, а второй для видео. Если нужно будет, пишите. Поправлю код.